# text_widget.insert(1.0, "\\") will only display one slash

Tags: python, string, tkinter, ascii

The title says all. I have the following code, lines 9 and 18 contain said characters. Is there a way without using chr(92)?

```
def Conversion(self):
    self.t=self.input.Read()   
    self.columns=1    
    for i in range(len(self.t)):
        if self.t[i]==chr(9):
            self.columns+=1
        elif self.t[i]==chr(10):
            break             
    self.c="\begin{tabular} ["       
    self.c+="c"*self.columns
    self.c+="] \n"
    for i in range(len(self.t)):
        #self.c+=str(ord(self.t[i]))
        #self.c+=" "
        if self.t[i]==chr(9):
            self.c+='&'
        elif self.t[i]==chr(10):
            self.c+='\\'
            self.c+="\n"
        else:
            self.c+=self.t[i] 
    self.c+="\end{tabular}"
    self.output.Write(self.c)
```

Also my .Write method looks like this:

```
class Output:
def __init__(self,master,x):
    self.v=Text(master,width=x)
    self.v.pack(side=RIGHT)
    self.v.insert(1.0,"LaTeX code")
def Write (self,input):
    self.input=input
    if self.v.get(1.0,END)=="":
        self.v.insert(1.0,self.input)
    else:
        self.v.delete(1.0,END)
        self.v.insert(1.0,self.input)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try escaping the `\` character, each time you need a `\` in the text, write two `\` like this:

```
self.c='\\begin{tabular} ['
```

Or use [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
self.c=r'\begin{tabular} ['
```

Comment: The first method gave errors with three slashes ('///') but the second worked perfectly. Can you explain what the r actually does? What is escaping?

Comment: For the first method: each time you need a \, write _two_. That's why \\\ will fail but \\\\ will work. For the second method, an `r''` string is called a [raw string](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) and uses different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences

Comment: There are some characters that have special meaning in string (for instance: ``\`` which is used to write invisible charaters :`\n`, `\t`... or `"` which specifiy the end of the string. Escaping refers to using this characters in a string (this characters and not their abstract role). It is done in Python (as well as in many other languages) by adding a ``\`` ahead, for instance `"Mark says \"Hello!\"."`, or in your case `"\\"`